# Django User model fields at AdminModel

Tags: django, django-admin, user-profile

My purpose is to see at the admin site only user name, email and phone number.

I've create UserProfile by extending User model:

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True,blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)


    def user_email(self):
        return self.user.email
```

admin.py

```
from myApp.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib import admin


class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):



    fields = ('name','phone',)
    list_display   = ('name','user_email',)


 admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

so on the list_display it works, I can see only the columns I've chosen, but when I add 'user_email' ( **fields = ('name','user_email', 'phone',**) )to fields I get when I try to go to admin site:

'UserProfileAdmin.fields' refers to field 'user_email' that is missing from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Fields on a related model use *two* underscores. Dunno if it'll work in the admin though.

```
list_display   = ('name','user__email',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I recently used it and you maybe want this, too: If you wan't to add an inline admin to the "User" admin page in Django you can do this (at least in Django 1.3) by doing:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from models import UserProfile


class UserProfileInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInlineAdmin ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing, here is a post from 2010 (bless google): http://blog.timc3.com/2010/02/18/extending-djangos-user-admin/

Comment: OK thanks for all the answers , but this is not what I tried to do. I'm not trying to replace django adminUser I'm trying to leave django User model as is, I want to have in my project another user type that in the future could maybe login to the system but now i want only to take is details and send him emails,newsletter etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put editable fields from a related model into an admin form, without using inlines. You can show the field as a readonly value: just add it to `readonly_fields`.